# how to loop to export mutiple users attendance in excel using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf, mpdf, time-and-attendance

```
$getdateRangeVal = $this->getdaterange($from, $to);
        $arrstatus = array();
        $arrEmp = array();
        foreach($_data as $mp) {
            $empdata[] = array(
                'emp_primary' => $mp->emp_primary,
                'date' => $mp->date,
            );          
        }



        foreach ($_data as $value) {            
            $arrstatus[$value->emp_primary] = $value;
            for($i = 0; $i<sizeof($getdateRangeVal); $i++){
                $compare = array("date"=>$getdateRangeVal[$i],"emp_primary"=>$value->emp_primary);
                $key = array_search($compare, $empdata);
                if(strlen($key) > 0) {

                    $arrstatus[$value->emp_primary]->dateRange[] = array(
                        "status" => "P",
                        "getdateRangeVal" => $getdateRangeVal[$i],
                        "intime" => $_data[$key]->in_time,
                        "outtime" => $_data[$key]->out_time,
                        "totaltime" => $_data[$key]->total_time,
                    );
                } else {
                    $arrstatus[$value->emp_primary]->dateRange[] = array(
                        "status"=>"A",
                        "getdateRangeVal"=>$getdateRangeVal[$i],
                        "intime" => "",
                        "outtime" => "",
                        "totaltime" => "",
                    );

                }
            }
        }


            $sheet->setCellValue('A5', 'EMP ID');
            $sheet->setCellValue('D5', 'EMP NAME');
            $sheet->setCellValue('A6', 'Days');
            $sheet->setCellValue('A7', 'Status');
            $sheet->setCellValue('A8', 'IN time');
            $sheet->setCellValue('A9', 'Out time');
            $sheet->setCellValue('A10', 'Total time');

            $arr = array(

                '0' => 'B',
                '1' => 'C',
                '2' => 'D',
                '3' => 'E',
                '4' => 'F',
                '5' => 'G',
                '6' => 'H',
                '7' => 'I',
                '8' => 'J',
                '9' => 'K',
                '10' => 'L',
                '11' => 'M',
                '12' => 'N',
                '13' => 'O',
                '14' => 'P',
                '15' => 'Q',
                '16' => 'R',
                '17' => 'S',
                '18' => 'T',
                '19' => 'U',
                '20' => 'V',
                '21' => 'W',
                '22' => 'X',
                '23' => 'Y',
                '24' => 'Z',
                '25' => 'AA',
                '26' => 'AB',
                '27' => 'AC',
                '28' => 'AD',
                '29' => 'AE',
                '30' => 'AF',
             );

            $i= 0;

            $rowCount = 6;
            $statusCount = 7;
            $inCount = 8;
            $outCount = 9;
            $totalCount = 10;
$employeeId= $empdata[$i]['emp_primary'];

            foreach($arrstatus[$employeeId]->dateRange as $val){
                $sheet->setCellValue($arr[$i].$rowCount, date('j D',strtotime($val['getdateRangeVal'])));
                if($val['status'] == 'P'){
                    $sheet->setCellValue($arr[$i].$statusCount, $val['status']);
                }else{
                    $sheet->setCellValue($arr[$i].$statusCount, $val['status']);
                }
                $sheet->setCellValue($arr[$i].$inCount,$val['intime']);
                $sheet->setCellValue($arr[$i].$outCount, $val['outtime']);
                $sheet->setCellValue($arr[$i].$totalCount, $val['totaltime']);
$i++;

            }
```

===================================

This is my data

```
Array
(
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [firstname] => Amol
            [lastname] => Auti
            [enrollment] => 123456789
            [designation] => Android Developer
            [department] => Development 
            [emp_primary] => 1
            [emp_id] => 1001
            [company_name] => Maverick Solution
            [logo] => logo-1-1535090442cbrand-img6.png
            [company_address] => Cidco N-4
            [id] => 5
            [in_time] => 09:00:00
            [out_time] => 9:00:00
            [total_time] => 00:00:00.000000
            [date] => 2018-08-06
            [device_id] => 12:12:12:12
            [dateRange] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [status] => A
                            [getdateRangeVal] => 2018-08-01
                            [intime] => 
                            [outtime] => 
                            [totaltime] => 
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [status] => A
                            [getdateRangeVal] => 2018-08-02
                            [intime] => 
                            [outtime] => 
                            [totaltime] => 
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [status] => A
                            [getdateRangeVal] => 2018-08-03
                            [intime] => 
                            [outtime] => 
                            [totaltime] => 
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [status] => P
                            [getdateRangeVal] => 2018-08-04
                            [intime] => 09:00:00
                            [outtime] => 16:00:00
                            [totaltime] => 07:00:00.000000
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [status] => P
                            [getdateRangeVal] => 2018-08-05
                            [intime] => 09:00:00
                            [outtime] => 16:00:00
                            [totaltime] => 07:00:00.000000
                        )

                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [status] => P
                            [getdateRangeVal] => 2018-08-06
                            [intime] => 09:00:00
                            [outtime] => 9:00:00
                            [totaltime] => 00:00:00.000000
                        )

                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [status] => A
                            [getdateRangeVal] => 2018-08-07
                            [intime] => 
                            [outtime] => 
                            [totaltime] => 
                        )

                    [7] => Array
                        (
                            [status] => A
                            [getdateRangeVal] => 2018-08-08
                            [intime] => 
                            [outtime] => 
                            [totaltime] => 
                        )

                    [8] => Array
                        (
                            [status] => A
                            [getdateRangeVal] => 2018-08-09
                            [intime] => 
                            [outtime] => 
                            [totaltime] => 
                        )

                    [9] => Array
                        (
                            [status] => A
                            [getdateRangeVal] => 2018-08-10
                            [intime] => 
                            [outtime] => 
                            [totaltime] => 
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [firstname] => Sumit
            [lastname] => Malusare
            [enrollment] => 135454
            [designation] => Web Developer
            [department] => Development 
            [emp_primary] => 2
            [emp_id] => 1002
            [company_name] => Maverick Solution
            [logo] => logo-1-1535090442cbrand-img6.png
            [company_address] => Cidco N-4
            [id] => 20
            [in_time] => 09:00:00
            [out_time] => 18:00:00
            [total_time] => 09:00:00.000000
            [date] => 2018-08-05
            [device_id] => 12:12:12:12
            [dateRange] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [status] => A
                            [getdateRangeVal] => 2018-08-01
                            [intime] => 
                            [outtime] => 
                            [totaltime] => 
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [status] => A
                            [getdateRangeVal] => 2018-08-02
                            [intime] => 
                            [outtime] => 
                            [totaltime] => 
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [status] => A
                            [getdateRangeVal] => 2018-08-03
                            [intime] => 
                            [outtime] => 
                            [totaltime] => 
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [status] => A
                            [getdateRangeVal] => 2018-08-04
                            [intime] => 
                            [outtime] => 
                            [totaltime] => 
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [status] => P
                            [getdateRangeVal] => 2018-08-05
                            [intime] => 09:00:00
                            [outtime] => 18:00:00
                            [totaltime] => 09:00:00.000000
                        )

                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [status] => A
                            [getdateRangeVal] => 2018-08-06
                            [intime] => 
                            [outtime] => 
                            [totaltime] => 
                        )

                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [status] => A
                            [getdateRangeVal] => 2018-08-07
                            [intime] => 
                            [outtime] => 
                            [totaltime] => 
                        )

                    [7] => Array
                        (
                            [status] => A
                            [getdateRangeVal] => 2018-08-08
                            [intime] => 
                            [outtime] => 
                            [totaltime] => 
                        )

                    [8] => Array
                        (
                            [status] => A
                            [getdateRangeVal] => 2018-08-09
                            [intime] => 
                            [outtime] => 
                            [totaltime] => 
                        )

                    [9] => Array
                        (
                            [status] => A
                            [getdateRangeVal] => 2018-08-10
                            [intime] => 
                            [outtime] => 
                            [totaltime] => 
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

===========================
I have to print like that

```
Report - Attendance Sheet
Duration - 1-Aug-18 TO 10-Aug-18
Name    Amol Auti   
Emp code    1001
Enrollment number   123456789   
Department  Development Designation Android Developer
Date    1-Aug   2-Aug   3-Aug   4-Aug   5-Aug   6-Aug   7-Aug   8-Aug   9-Aug   10-Aug
Status  A   A   A   P   P   P   A   A   A   A
In Time -   -   -   09:00:00    09:00:00    09:00:00    -   -   -   -
Out Time    -   -   -   16:00:00    16:00:00    9:00:00 -   -   -   -
Total Time  -   -   -   07:00:00.000000 07:00:00.000000 00:00:00.000000 -   -   -   -
Name    Sumit Malusare  Emp code    1002
Enrollment number   135454  
Department  Development 
Designation Web Developer
Date    1-Aug   2-Aug   3-Aug   4-Aug   5-Aug   6-Aug   7-Aug   8-Aug   9-Aug   10-Aug
Status  A   A   A   A   P   A   A   A   A   A
In Time -   -   -   -   09:00:00    -   -   -   -   -
Out Time    -   -   -   -   18:00:00    -   -   -   -   -
Total Time  -   -   -   -   09:00:00.000000 -   -   -   -   -
```

Comment: i have to export excel vertically i am using mpdf library

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to export that on excel, you need to use a library for that.

here is an awesome tutorial on how to convert your data to excel file.

https://arjunphp.com/how-to-use-phpexcel-with-codeigniter/.

that's what i'm using now on my project. hope that helps.

Comment: i have already used library but i have issue in loop to print ouput in excel horizontaly

Comment: @VishalBondre what do you mean horizontal, the output?

Comment: please take a look at last code in question u will understand how i wants to print excelsheet